# How to get web element value and compare it with a number in Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

In web page, there is a `total amount` field as a `short` (I guess), not an `int`.
I want to take this web-element and compare it with a number (ie: "total amount" value is smaller than "500.80".
I am trying to use the `BuiltIn` library but I cannot find any related keyword.

web elements are:

```
<strong data-bind="text: cartItemPrice">20.947,88</strong>
```

xpath:

```
//*[@id="item-prices"]/div/div[1]/div/strong
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SeleniumLibrary`'s [Get Text keyword](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Get%20Text) to get the value, convert it to integer or number, and then evaluate it.

In this solution, `SeleniumLibrary` and `String` libraries should be imported.

E.g.

```
${actual_value}=    Get Text    example_locator_id
${val}=    Remove String    ${actual_value}    .
${val}=    Replace String    ${val}    ,    .
${val}=    Convert To Number    ${val}
Should Be True    ${val} < 50
```

If the web GUI value is a float, then use `Convert To Number` instead of `Convert To Integer`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I have this output when try your solution, can you pls check; failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

Comment: i use "id" as a locator, should i use something else to get text of a locator?

Comment: There should be no SyntaxError here. Yes, id is the best locator strategy. Without any source HTML code, it's difficult to help more...

Comment: Just checked the code in another website and it works. That is actually an xpath locator... Please paste the code you are trying in the question part. Also, that number is not an integer...

Comment: thanks, I edited my question. your solution absolutely works in normal conditions. but I guess I ask my question uncorrectly.  I hope you can review again.

Comment: My code should not produce that kind of error. Seems like you are assigning the xpath locator to `val` or `actual_value` variable instead of getting the text there, and later use that variable in comparing.

Comment: it works!!! thank you so much! The problem was i accidently added my ${xx} values to "variables" instead of "keywords". it is kind a confusing for new starters like me.

Comment: Great! If it works, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: can you please share your experience abut how can you check the result and check "that code is working well" without having whole code? is there a tool about it?

Comment: Perhaps that could be done using Jupyter notebook now that it has Robot Framework support. Otherwise, years of experience.