# selenium robot framework -how to get element description

Tags: robotframework

I'm new on RobotFramework and have an issue as below.
Can someone help me on this?

```
<div id="cdk-describedby-message-41" role="tooltip">Open</div>
```

I would like to get "Open" from this element locator

I tried to use:

```
${des}   Get Element Attribute     //*[@id="${cdk-describedby-message-41}"]     role
Log To Console     ${des}
```

It would print out "tooltip"

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, it's not a description it's an element value!
Then you're using `Get Element Attribute` keyword. Attributes in this element are `id` and `role`, you should use `Get Text` keyword instead!

Here is a answer! [How to get web element value and compare it with a number in Robot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59245119/how-to-get-web-element-value-and-compare-it-with-a-number-in-robot-framework)

Comment: Thank you for looking in my issue.
I resolved it

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue:

```
${des}   Get Element Attribute     //*[@id="${cdk-describedby-message-41}"]     textContent
```